Destatis Genesis API
I want to import table data from the Statistisches Bundesamt Deutschland into my Python program and use the data for some calculations. I want to write generic code that processes the server response. The code must be able to process the response, no matter what table I want, and create a pandas DataFrame. However, it seems that the response for every table is different. For example:
"Content": "GENESIS-Tabelle: 46131-0002\nBeförderte Güter, Beförderungsleistung;;;;;\n(Eisenbahngüterverkehr): Deutschland, Monate;;;;;\nGüterverkehrsstatistik der Eisenbahn;;;;;\nDeutschland;;;;;\n;;Beförderte Güter;Veränderung zum Vorjahresmonat;Beförderungsleistung;Veränderung zum Vorjahresmonat\n;;t;in (%);tkm;in (%)\n2024;Januar;25480080;-8,9;9260771423;-9,7\n2024;Februar;28411584;+3,2;10770061996;+4,6\n2024;März;...;...;...;...\n2024;April;...;...;...;...\n2024;Mai;...;...;...;...\n2024;Juni;...;...;...;...\n2024;Juli;...;...;...;...\n2024;August;...;...;...;...\n2024;September;...;...;...;...\n2024;Oktober;...;...;...;...\n2024;November;...;...;...;...\n2024;Dezember;...;...;...;...\n__________\n© Statistisches Bundesamt (Destatis), 2024\nStand: 30.05.2024 / 12:28:59\n", 

and the second response is:
"Content": "GENESIS-Tabelle: 46321-0002\nBeförderte Güter, Beförderungsleistung (Binnenschifffahrt):;;;;;;;;;\nDeutschland, Monate, Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;;;;;;;;;\nGüterverkehrsstatistik der Binnenschifffahrt;;;;;;;;;\nDeutschland;;;;;;;;;\n;;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen;Hauptverkehrsbeziehungen\n;;Verkehr innerhalb Deutschlands;Verkehr innerhalb Deutschlands;Grenzüberschreitender Versand;Grenzüberschreitender Versand;Grenzüberschreitender Empfang;Grenzüberschreitender Empfang;Durchgangsverkehr;Durchgangsverkehr\n;;Beförderte Güter;Beförderungsleistung;Beförderte Güter;Beförderungsleistung;Beförderte Güter;Beförderungsleistung;Beförderte Güter;Beförderungsleistung\n;;t;Mill. Tkm;t;Mill. Tkm;t;Mill. Tkm;t;Mill. Tkm\n2024;Januar;3149238;577;3586816;965;6409496;1294;895290;584\n2024;Februar;3493678;704;3746119;1070;6123775;1267;870534;585\n2024;März;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;April;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;Mai;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;Juni;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;Juli;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;August;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;September;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;Oktober;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;November;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n2024;Dezember;...;...;...;...;...;...;...;...\n__________\nMill. Tkm = Millionen Tonnenkilometer\n© Statistisches Bundesamt (Destatis), 2024\nStand: 30.05.2024 / 12:35:13\n",

I have no idea how to retrieve my column names and all row data. Can you please help me?
I wrote to the support team and have not yet received an answer.
